# Delphi Source Editor, column pasting not working properly when the line has special characters

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I am using now Delphi 10 Seattle, and there was a functionality that I used a lot but now I'm having problems with it.

On source code editor to select and paste text/code in a specific column instead of the default block paste.

If you hold ALT when selecting the text you want to copy/paste, when you paste it, the editor pastes all the lines selected over the existing text, but only to the right of the selected text, like, in this example code:

I select the code using left ALT, then click on the position I want to paste, and when I paste, it pastes all lines, moving the existing code to the right

[image: Selected code to paste]

[image: Positioned to paste code]

[image: Code is pasted through column paste]

However, when I paste the code over lines that have special characters (like á, à, ã, õ, ç, ò, etc. ), the pasting doesn't consider these letters and the pasted text is pasted unindented.

Is there a way to counter this? it worked perfectly on Delphi 7, Delphi XE3 has the same problem tough.

Comment: Submit a bug report.

Comment: Indeed, this is something Embarcadero's gonna have to fix, not us.

Comment: I asked here because I found solutions to similar problems with portuguese language, like the ] key not working on some enviroments. Thank you anyway...